# How to define a symbol for total image size or its end address in IAR linker script?

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I'd like to define a symbol in IAR C program to get the total size (or the end address) of the image, **in the build time**, so that this size or offset will be contained in the image after linking.

(I know that this can  be done in a post-build action. Also, I know how to do this with the gnu linker)

The IAR documentation on expressions in the link scripts says about functions 'size' and 'end'. The problem is that I don't know the section or segment names.

From the map file, the linker creates sections named P1, P2, A1, and so on. The read-only code + data + init data section is likely what I want, it is named "P1".

Snippet from the map file:

```
*******************************************************************************
*** PLACEMENT SUMMARY
***

"A0":  place at address 0x800'8000 { ro section .intvec };
"P1":  place in [from 0x800'8000 to 0x807'ffff] { ro };
.......... etc.......
```

I tried: `define exported symbol MY_SIZE = size("P1");` or `define exported symbol MY_SIZE = size(P1);` but get error message "Error[Lc007]: expected an identifier". "Error[Lc010]: "P1" is not a region name".

What is the correct argument for size and end functions? Or any other way to do this?

Comment: IAR EWARM version 8.40

Comment: "to get the total size (...) of the image, in the build time," --> `sizeof(image)`.

Comment: Can you explain why and where you need this information, and why post-build action doesn't work?

Comment: @chux I think *image* refers here to the built binary, rather than single data object.

Comment: @user694733 There is a lot here that is not detailed, yet deserves to be.  As for me, it would help if OP posted the relevant C code.

Comment: @user694733 I want to place the image size in fixed location (like, in unused interrupt vector) so bootloader can check the image. I want this to go into the elf file, to be able to load the program in the debugger, before conversion to bin, hex etc. With gnu linker this is easy, but customer has IAR.

Comment: > I think image refers here to the built binary, rather than single data object. -- not even to the built binary (yet), just to the size of the read-only section that goes to the internal flash (whatever this is called in IAR). When the image has been built, its size should be this size (without stuff that goes to external flash).

Comment: I don't know if this can be done with linker script, but if you want to modify the elf file, you could perhaps do this: Create post build script which will determine the size (possibly with `ielfdump`), and then patch elf file with `ielftool` command (`--fill` parameter perhaps?). You might have to make sure that target location is not used by excluding it in linker script. I have used `ielftool` for patching, but not `ielfdump`, so you might have to experiment a little.

Comment: Yes thank you, I know about post-processing tools. I want to make debugging easy and intuitive for customer.

Comment: One thing that could work, but I haven't tested: Use `ielftool` to dump out required memory range in `.bin` format, and then check size of that file to figure out used size. Not sure if if this works.

Comment: *"I want to make debugging easy and intuitive for customer."* It shouldn't affect the debugger if you modify the elf file in post build step. Or to put it better; debugger could use the patched elf.

Comment: How to define a block or section that is placed very last in the image, even after auto-generated RAM init data? then I could get its address using custom IAR intrinsic(?)  __section_begin

Comment: > debugger could use the patched elf -- for me this could work but customer can forget the post-build step, or add a new configuration where it needs to be added.

Comment: *"How to define a block or section that is placed very last in the image, even after auto-generated RAM init data?"* You have probably have to use `place in` directive with extended selector `last` with the section name to place at the end.

Comment: If the customer can forget the post-build step, the build process is defect. Repair it (make it automatic) and you're done.

Comment: @user694733 I tried to use `place in ... last` but RAM initalizer bytes are still placed after it. <br>I tried:<br>```define root section END_S { udata32 0 ; } ;
define block END_B with alignment = 4 { section END_S };
place in USER_AXI_ROM_region  { last block END_B };```<br>

Comment: Unfortunately it's been a while since I've had to do it myself, and I cannot see what is wrong with your code. I would approach IAR support at this point, if it is possibility to you.

Comment: That's exactly why I'm asking here. My customer unfortunately does not have active support from IAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The current IAR linker comes with the `start()`, `end()` and `size()` functionalities. However, as for now, those only apply to regions.

```
define exported symbol _start_address = start(ROM_region);
define exported symbol _end_address = end(ROM_region);
```

However, in the linker configuration, regions are bound to literals. So, here the "_start_address" will refer to the initial address of the ROM_region and "_end_address" will be the ending address, which is independent from the program size.

An alternative approach for getting where the user program itself starts/ends can be to place 2 rooted dummy sections as wrappers around the sections actually being placed in the ROM_region:

```
define root section _start_section with alignment = 4 { public _ss: udata32 0xA5A5A5A5; };
define root section _end_section with alignment = 4 { public _es: udata32 0xBABABABA; };

"ROM": place in ROM_region { first section _start_section,
                             ro,
                             last section _end_section };
```

From the C program (/debugger) these addresses can be accessed directly via "extern":

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  extern const void * _ss;
  extern const void * _es;
  printf("Initial 32-bit address: 0x%08x\n", &_ss);
  printf("Final 32-bit address: 0x%08x\n", &_es);
}
/* Output example (Terminal I/O) */
// Initial 32-bit address: 0x08000000
// Final 32-bit address: 0x08000B68
```

If your program's "ROM_region" has complex partitioning, the same concept would still be potentially usable as far as the "start section" and "end section" are placed in a *fixed order* block which lumps all the sections/blocks other than "ro":

```
define block RO_BLOCK with fixed order, end alignment = 4 {
                                         section _start_section,
                                         ro,
                                         /* sections/blocks other than "ro" */
                                         section _end_section };
                                         
"ROM": place in ROM_region { block RO_BLOCK };
```

Either way, the addresses are defined within the ELF at linking time, without the need for an external utility to patch it during a post-build step.